# PDF Viewer on Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, pdf, embed, sencha-touch-2

I have got a weird situation on Sencha touch2 .

I have an issue to read and display the PDF file in this framework. I read about this on sencha forum/google .etc and I didn't really find a real solution.

I have an JSON object feed with PDF's url (PDFs are not locally) .

what I tried this:

---

- `<embed type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" src="file.pdf" />`

  I have have scroll issue, t shows just first page, because Sencha has got own scroll panel ... etc

---

- `<object data="YourFile.pdf" TYPE="application/x-pdf" width="100%" height="100%" </object>`

it has the same thing, scrolling issue

---

- `<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url='+encodeURI+'&embedded=true" width="100%" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>`

I kind of liked the google idea, but by nor reason it did not worked on my Ipad, I think google requires to be logged in, in case you want to read view the PDF

---

PS: All these 3 methots i set as an HTML in sencha panel:

```
            {
                xtype:'panel',
                height:'100%'
                html:'iframe or object or google'
            }
```

Did someone find a solution or maybe workaround anything to view the pdf files ?

Thanks for ay help !!!!!

Comment: Have you found a solution? When it shows the first page Does It allow you to open in aother reader when you are on an iPad? Thanks a lot

Comment: The problem is not only that the page doesn't scroll...on iOS it seems a static image (and It seems to me that it has an incorrect size) and you cannot do nothing inside it.

Comment: Do you have any alternative to that? Not opening a document (PDF or other formats is not so important) in a ST2 Panel is a huge defect...

Comment: The iframe has problem with the size of the PDF. For me, in the iPad Safari the PDF is not sized well and the right part of it is out of the view...Do you have same problem?

Comment: nothing works, I am using for now  alternative way, which is google pdf viewer. But still not the best solution for me , still looking for some real solution

Answer (score 1):

I found few alternatives which I use or I have in plan to use:

1. Google PDF viewer https://docs.google.com/viewer, which is not perfect for me and it has got some session issue when you are logged in and session is expired
2. In case your app is fine to open a new window the PDF, you can open a new window in Browser version and you can use in Phonegap ChildBrowser for example to view the pdf
3. I use to use for 1 app a third party servie ex: http://crocdoc.com/, but doesn't really work for me, cause I nee to upload pdf in http://crocdoc.com/ after I can preview in app, which is not on the fly
4. Next in line for me is using pdfjs https://github.com/SunboX/st2_pdf_panel. I will still have to play with cross domain documents, but this is all I got.

If you have a real solution that would be awesome, but this issue it is been for a wile in my app implementation time, not sure which is the real an solution in this situation.

Comment: Do you need to use PhoneGap to open the PDF in a new window? An alternative for me is to load a short image preview of the PDF in ST2 and load the PDF in a new Window in Safari. But I do not know if this is possible without PhoneGap...thanks a lot

Comment: O yeah, that is possible. it doesn't work just in my case, because I want to keep all users in the app and not leaving the app. But in case it is fine for you, it is not a problem and for sure possible. Just 1 bug you will have, when you app is going to be  as "HOME SCREEN Shortcut" (Ipad/Iphone case), you do not have Browser's frame and when you open the PDF you cannot go back in the actual app. (I hope it helped )

Comment: MHh, yeah but I need to put in the home the app. So for me is a problem. Thx a lot

Comment: I don't think the Google PDF viewer need you to log in anymore ? Like this one: https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://cdn.mozilla.net/pdfjs/tracemonkey.pdf&embedded=true . It can be a solution if you don't care about the confidentiality of the content

Answer (score 0):

Yes dear you can easily view pdf document on  sencha touch-2 using  the example below:

```
Ext.Viewport.add({
        //first we define the xtype, which is tabpanel for the Tab Panel component
        xtype: 'tabpanel',

        //next we define the items that will appear inside our tab panel
        items: [
            {
                //each item in a tabpanel requires the title configuration. this is displayed
                //on the tab for this item
                title: 'Tab 1',

                //next we give it some simple html
                items: {
                    html: '1',
                    centered: true
                },

                //then a custom cls so we can style it
                cls: 'card1'
            },
            {
                //title
                title: 'Tab 2',

                //the items html
                items: {
                    html: '2',
                    centered: true
                },

                //custom cls
                cls: 'card2'
            },
            {
                //title
                title: 'Tab 3',

                //the items html
                items: {
                    html: '<embed type="application/pdf" width="800px" height="800px" src="YourFile.pdf" />',
                    centered: true
                },

                //custom cls
                cls: 'card3'
            }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: it doesn't scroll, it shows jut the first page and that is all